# How tu transfer data between backend in spring boot and frontend vuejs

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have Json file in server and I want to send somme data from Backend(SpringBoot) to the frontend(vuejs ).

please does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an endpoint with your backend and return it via your backend application and consumes it with your frontend using axios or something like that. I really suggest you watch some of the great tutorials out there like :

[SringBoot Tutorial  by AmigosCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U&embeds_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2F&embeds_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=Amigoscode)

There's the documentation on axios :

[Axios with Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html?redirect=true)

Comment: Thank you, I will see it :) With this method I can Send one data or many data ?